A general solution $M$ for the matrix equation $A^* M^* + M A = 0$
As titled, for some unknown complex-valued matrix $A$, possibly rectangular, does there in general exist a complex-valued matrix $M$ such that
$$
A^* M^* + M A = 0 
$$
Here, $A^*$ denotes the Hermittian transpose, i.e., $\overline{A^\ast} = A^T$, where $\overline{\cdot}$ denotes the element-wise complex conjugation, and $\cdot^T$ denotes the transpose without conjugate. This is somewhat similar to a Sylvester equation but not exactly one because $A$ is not necessarily square, which means that $M$ too not sqaure, much less Hermittian, to make the equation a real Sylvester equation.
For example, if $A = aI$ for some arbitrary real constant $a$, then in general
$$
A^* M^* + M A = a(M^\ast + M) = 0 \iff M \text{ is skew-Hermittian}.
$$
However, for more general $A$ with only minimal information/structure known, e.g., its maximum singular value, does such $M$ always exist for the matrix equation to hold? I suspect that $M$ would have to be the zero matrix. As a simple example, consider $A = aI + \mathbf{j} bI$ for some real constants $a,b$, then the equation above reduces to the requirement that $M^{\ast} = -M = M \implies M = 0$. Am I correct?

The equation can always be solved by $M=iA^\ast$.

@user1551 That's certaintly true, but what if I don't know what $A$ is? I edited the question to highlight this.

It is a complex version of Sylvester equation as considered here.

@JeanMarie Hmm, that looks promising, thanks! But in my case the unknown is $M$, and both $M$ and its Hermittian transpose $M^{\ast}$ appear, not its complex conjugate $\overline{M}$, and it seems that my $M$ would be constrained to be symmetric for me to apply the results considered there...? But my $A$ matrix, which is "known" (only very limited information about $A$ is known) is not necessarily square and would result in a non-square $M$.

This is indeed a Sylvester-like equation, but the adjoint on $M$ prevents us to solve it in the same general way $-$ apart from particular solutions such as $M = iA^\dagger$ or by assuming that $M$ is hermitian (so that one faces a standard Lyapunov equation). Sylvester equations such as $AX + XB = C$ are usually handled through vectorization, i.e. by treating the unknown matrix $X$ as a vector $u = \operatorname{vec}(X)$ in a given basis (since matrices form a vector space) and rewriting the initial equation as a "standard" linear problem $Lu = v$, where $v = \operatorname{vec}(C)$, given that $L(X) := AX + XB$ is a linear operator, which can be expressed in the said basis too.
In the present case, the complex conjugation doesn't allow us to take advantage of the same procedure, because it is not $\Bbb{C}$-linear. In consequence, the matrix $M^\dagger$ has to be considered as (linearly) independent with respect to $M$, in the same spirit as it is usually done when one considers the complex variables $(z,\bar{z})$ as a basis of the complex plane instead of the canonical cartersian coordinates $(x,y)$.
Concretely, you have to recast the original problem as $CX - XD = 0$, where
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix} M & 0 \\ 0 & M^\dagger \end{pmatrix} , 
\quad
C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A^\dagger \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
\quad\text{and}\quad
D = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note that alternative parametrizations are possible. Now, this problem is linear and can be vectorized as $Lu = 0$, where $u = \operatorname{vec}{X}$ and $L = I_{2n} \otimes C - D^T \otimes I_{2n}$, so that the solution space will be the kernel of $L$.
Nevertheless, it is to be noted that one may "cheat" a little bit by noticing that the initial equation is equivalent to $MA = -(MA)^\dagger$, implying that $MA =: B$ is an antihermitian matrix, the latter equation being easier to treat.
